# Is there anyway to avoid 302 redirect before throwing 404?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

In MVC, defined customErrors path On statusCode 404 which is working as expected but returning status code 302, before 404.

Can we avoid that Temporary redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the attribute redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" on the customErrors tag of the web.config. Unfortunatly it only works with aspx, and doesn't work for ASP.NET MVC.

So to achieve what you want in MVC you have to handle the error to write the response that you want.

in Global.asax.cs :

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpException httpException = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException() as HttpException;

    if (httpException != null)
    {
        if (httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
        {
            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Errors");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error404");
            var requestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
            var controller = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(requestContext, "Errors");

            controller.Execute(requestContext);
        }
    }
}
```

this code will handle the 404 error, and call the action Error404 on the ErrorsController without doing a redirect.